# Unable to find "CreateDeploymentUtility" in SQL Server 2017

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2017

I observe that CreateDeploymentUtility is not available in same place as it should be as explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/zdxOxHM5Ijw?t=2m27s). By any chance do you know where I can find and set it?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, version 15.3.4, .Net Framework version 4.7.02046

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SQL Server 2017 Integration Services (SSIS) introduced the
>   Incremental Package Deployment feature that allows you to deploy one
>   or more packages without deploying the whole project.

To Deploye follow steps given in below Link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages#PackageModel